# Algebraic groups of multiplicative type in char 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, number-theory, algebraic-groups

For a number field $k$ (so of char 0), are algebraic $k$-groups of multiplicative type always linear?

Comment: Any affine algebraic group is linear.  This is covered near the beginning of most texts on algebraic groups.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked whether groups of multiplicative type are always affine. Is the answer yes, then? (Sorry if this is kind of basic, but I'm a computer scientist by training and not an algebraic geometer, so I'm not really confident about this stuff.)

Comment: Yes, this is a basic descent argument.  One reference is SGA 3 Exp. IX Proposition 2.1, but there might be others that are easier for non-specialists.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is the result in SGA 3 that Scott Carnahan references, but the following is true:

> Suppose that we have a fibered diagram as follows
>   $$\begin{matrix}X & \to & Y\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow\\ T & \to & S\end{matrix}$$
>   where $T\to S$ is fpqc. Then, $Y\to S$ is affine, if and only if $X\to T$ is affine.

So, in your problem, if you start with an algebraic group $G/\text{Spec}(k)$, and the base change to $\text{Spec}(\overline{k})$, is affine, then the above implies that $G$ is affine.